# Kate Editor shortcut to Focus/Defocus terminal doesn't work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde-plasma, kate

I'm using Kate as the editor for some programs (Octave and sometimes MySQL). 
I really like Kate's functionality, at the moment I've really exploited the link between the editor and the terminal.

I have changed some shortcuts to fit my needs as I replicate the behavior from other programs (it's not a big difference but I mention RStudio, which I also use).

The relevant shortcuts are:  Show, Focus, Pipe and Synchronize Terminal.  Since I modified Focus Terminal (Ctrl+Volume Off -F1 key-, strange choice but effective because of mentioned similarity with RStudio), it only works one way but it doesn't take me back to the editor.  In addition, I noticed that the shortcut name changed to Defocus Terminal.

I'm using Kate version 5.0.0 on KDE Frameworks 5.9.0 and Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a shortcut to `View > Tool Views > Show Terminal`, this then works as expected. You may have to save the current session to make it persistent (probably a bug). Invoking the shortcut will then toggle this action.